# Spolied Meat Test?

Tags: beef, roast

I left a beef roast in a crock pot covered - 10 hours -forgot to plug it in. Meat was still cool to touch. Home kept at 72 degrees. Safe to cook and eat or throw it out?

Answer (score 1):

Throw out. Raw meat should not be kept at room temperature for more than 2 hours.